# ¿Canciones multi-escena en Unity?

Tags: unity, unity2d

Verán, quiero hacer una música de fondo en Unity pero quiero que siga aun así cambie de escena, saben si se puede?Y si es así, como?

Comment: bienvenido, por favor revisa [ask] lo ideal para que la comunidad sepa como apoyarte es que nos indiques lo que has tratado o investigado hasta el momento y en que parte de tu avance tuviste problemas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí es posible, lo idea es que en tu primer escena crees el objeto reproductor y agregues en su script principal lo siguiente:

```
private static bool created = false;

void Awake()
{
    if (!created)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        created = true;
        Debug.Log("Awake: " + this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Esto va permitir que tu reproductor siempre esté vivo, por ende el player seguira entre escenas...

Answer (score 0):

Sí, es posible como ha indicado @Calleth 'Zion', no obstante, lo completaría con la propia ayuda de Unity a la hora de escribir el GameManager, que no es ni más ni menos que hacer una clase singlenton. Ya que sino lo haces así, y en tu nueva escena también tienes ese objeto (porque quieras probar las escenas de manera separada) se te acumularan los objetos haciendote un audio doble.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SingletonExample : MonoBehaviour {

private static SingletonExample _instance;

void Awake(){

    if (_instance == null){

        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);

        //Rest of your Awake code

    } else {
        Destroy(this);
    }
}

//Rest of your class code

}
```